# Error when trying to generate devise:install in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm a new to Ruby on Rails and I tried to do some examples from Internet. But I have an error when I'm trying to generate devise install.
I modified the Gemfile by adding **gem devise**. Then run:

```
bundle install
```

but when I run.

```
rails generate devise:install
```

I had the next error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/0.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.3/lib/devise.rb:193:in `mailer=': undefined method `ref' for ActiveSupport::Dependencies:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.3/lib/devise.rb:195:in `<module:Devise>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.3/lib/devise.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/mihai/Desktop/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Please help me!

Comment: can you post part of your Gemfile where you include gem 'devise'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version of Devise is rather old.

You can do:

```
bundle update devise
```

And then:

```
bundle install
```

This should upgrade the Devise gem.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to put this inside your `Gemfile` instead of just `gem 'devise'`

```
gem 'devise', github: 'ghiculescu/devise', branch: 'patch-2'
```

Re-run `bundle install`

and then you can do `rails generate devise:install`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
rails generate devise_install
```

and not:

```
rails generate devise:install
```